# IDA Pro and editing executables

Tags: executable, patch, ida

This is kind of an unorthodox question.

I'm kinda new to using IDA Pro.
Is there a way to edit the assembly code and then have IDA save the result as an executable?
Is there some kind of plugin maybe that does that? because it seems that IDA doesn't want to save as an EXE.
Or do I need to manually edit it in some other way?

Comment: Well, I ended up using OllyDbg. It makes it very easy to patch an exe.

Answer (score 4):

Version 6.1+ (maybe 6.2+) of IDA Pro will allow you to apply your patches directly to the input file. Equally, it allows you to revert the changes back.

Comment: The menu is a bit difficult to find; it's under Edit > Patch Program. That menu is also where you need to save the result.

Comment: @tomysshadow Thanks. I was wondering why my patches hadn't been applied to the binary. I had to use `Edit -> Patch Program -> Apply patches to input file...`

Answer (score 0):

I've seen somewhere else that you'd have to produce a .diff file from there then open with a text editor and use another program to patch the original file.