# IDA pro asm instructions change

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, ida

I just want to know how I can
change asm instructions in the IDA-view A:

1. How to edit instructions(for
   instance: jnz to jmp)?
2. How to insert new instructions(call func1,
   call func2 inserted to existing
   code)?

I know how to make dif files, I know how to apply the changes on my DLL, but how can
I "make the difference"? How can I edit the code in IDA?

I learned how to modify a DLL:

1. Modify code(how?)
2. Generate dif file.
3. Apply the code modifications to the DLL with the dif file and a script.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IDA Pro and editing executables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327196/ida-pro-and-editing-executables)

Answer (score 21):

1. There is a `Edit / Patch` menu that used to be shown by default but that is hidden in recent IDA releases. If it is your case, edit the `cfg/idagui.cfg` file, look for the `DISPLAY_PATCH_SUBMENU = NO` line and change the setting. On the next IDA session, you will be able to change single byte / word values or assemble some code like in OllyDbg.
2. Once you have patched your database, go to `File / Produce file / Create DIF file`, it will let you create a simple diff file in the form offset / value before / value after (it is not the common diff file format)
3. To apply the diff file to an existing file, you can use the source code of a [dif file patcher](http://www.idabook.com/examples/chapter_14/ida_patcher.c) that was released in the [IDA Pro Book](http://idabook.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Use `Edit->patch program->assemble`  to write in assembly syntax

Use `Edit->patch program -> patch bytes` to edit bytes in the binary

Finally, use `Edit->patch program -> apply patch to input file`
to apply patches. I'v personally used it in IDA 7.0

Answer (score 2):

Try IDA Pro 6.1 or 6.2. It has the ability to write the changes to the input file directly.

Comment: How ? I couldn't find it in IDA.